# MediaElement endedEvent keeps looping

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

This is my problem, I have a program that reads a list of strings with the name of the videos, and another with "Fill videos" that play whenever he video currently playing doesn't exist or the video fill has reached it's end. Heres the code:

```
        private const string VIDEO_EXTENSION = "*.mp4";
        private int randIndex = 0, seconds = 0;
        private string vidName = null;
        private static string DIRECTORY = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory"];

        private DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DIRECTORY);
        private DispatcherTimer videoPlaytimVerification = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        private List<VideoEntity.Video> videoPlayList = new List<VideoEntity.Video>();
        private List<VideoEntity.VideoTails> videoPlayListFill = new List<VideoEntity.VideoTails>();

    MediaElement me = new MediaElement();

    Log log = new Log();

    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        seconds = (int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;

        VideoEntity.Video Video1 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "572ce78adc.mp4", 52800);
        VideoEntity.Video Video2 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "025158ad58.mp4", 52810);
        VideoEntity.Video Video3 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "3b630e28b6.mp4", 52820);
        VideoEntity.Video Video4 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "49fcb4efba.mp4", 52830);
        VideoEntity.Video Video5 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "572ce78adc.mp4", 52840);
        VideoEntity.Video Video6 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "025158ad58.mp4", 52850);
        VideoEntity.Video Video7 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "3b630e28b6.mp4", 52860);
        VideoEntity.Video Video8 = new VideoEntity.Video(1, 10, 10, "49fcb4efba.mp4", 52870);

        videoPlayList.Add(Video1);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video2);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video3);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video4);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video5);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video6);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video7);
        videoPlayList.Add(Video8);

        VideoEntity.VideoTails Tail1 = new VideoEntity.VideoTails("H_encontra_10.mp4", "somthing");
        VideoEntity.VideoTails Tail2 = new VideoEntity.VideoTails("H_have_fun_10.mp4", "somthing");
        VideoEntity.VideoTails Tail3 = new VideoEntity.VideoTails("H_informa-te_10.mp4", "somthing");
        VideoEntity.VideoTails Tail4 = new VideoEntity.VideoTails("H_move-te_10.mp4", "somthing");
        VideoEntity.VideoTails Tail5 = new VideoEntity.VideoTails("H_selfie_10.mp4", "somthing");

        videoPlayListFill.Add(Tail1);
        videoPlayListFill.Add(Tail2);
        videoPlayListFill.Add(Tail3);
        videoPlayListFill.Add(Tail4);
        videoPlayListFill.Add(Tail5);

        LoadFillVideo();

        videoPlaytimVerification.Tick += new EventHandler(videoPlaytimVerification_Tick);
        videoPlaytimVerification.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        videoPlaytimVerification.Start();


    }

    #region METHODS

    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/

    private bool SearchVideo(string vidName)
    {
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (vidName == file.ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/

    void createMediaElement(string videoSource)
    {
        me.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        me.Source = new Uri(DIRECTORY + videoSource, UriKind.Absolute);
        me.Play();
        mediaPlayerGrid.Children.Add(me);
    }

    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/


    private void LoadFillVideo()
    {
       log.LogMessage("videoFill");

        Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.ToString().GetHashCode());
        randIndex = rand.Next(0, videoPlayListFill.Count);
        try
        {
            mediaPlayerGrid.Children.Remove(me);
            createMediaElement(videoPlayListFill[randIndex].Filename);
            VideoEnd(me, videoPlayListFill[randIndex].Filename);
        }
        catch { }
    }



    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/

    private void VideoEnd(MediaElement me, string vidName)
    {
        me.MediaEnded += (a, b) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Passei no evento ended");
            LoadFillVideo();
        };
    }

    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    #endregion

    #region EVENTS

    private void videoPlaytimVerification_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(seconds);

        foreach (VideoEntity.Video vid in videoPlayList)
        {
            if (vid.Playtime == seconds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     " + vid.Filename);

                vidName = vid.Filename;

                try
                {
                    mediaPlayerGrid.Children.Remove(me);
                    createMediaElement(vidName);
                    VideoEnd(me, vidName);
                }
                catch { }

                if (!SearchVideo(vidName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Passei no dispatcher = > loadfill");
                    LoadFillVideo();
                    seconds++;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if (seconds >= 89990)
            seconds = 3599;



        seconds++;
    }

    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/
    /*###############################################*/



    #endregion

}
```

When I run my code, and try to follow it, the first time the video fill ends, it's good, it only passes once at the VideoEnd(), but the second time, it goes like this LoadFill() -> VideoEnd() -> LoadFill() -> VideoEnd(),

and the third time like this:

LoadFill() -> VideoEnd() -> LoadFill() -> VideoEnd() -> LoadFill() -> VideoEnd() -> LoadFill() -> VideoEnd()

It goes on like this, increasing exponentially. Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block:

```
private void VideoEnd(MediaElement me, string vidName)
{
    me.MediaEnded += (a, b) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Passei no evento ended");
        LoadFillVideo();
    };
}
```

Every time `VideoEnd` is invoked, you create a new anonymous delegate, and subscribe to the `MediaEnded` event.

Note that you can have multiple delegates listening to the one event. So, adding a new subscriber doesn't make the old subscribers stop listening. This is why the first time you will have one call to `LoadFill`, the second time you have two subscribers, the third time you have three etc.

You must only subscribe to the `MediaEnded` event once.

```
void MediaEnded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    LoadFillVideo();
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    me.MediaEnded += MediaEnded;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, didn't even realized that <.<. Again thank you so much.